# Google Chrome plugin 

Tags: plugins, google-chrome

How does one go about embedding an application inside a web page shown in the Google Chrome browser like Adobe does with its Flash Chrome plug-in ? Is there an Api available to create Google chrome plugins ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome (and many other browsers) support the [Netscape Plugin API (NPAPI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Plugin_Application_Programming_Interface)

Comment: It's supported by every major browser but IE, and even IE supported it up to version 5.5 (Beyond 5.5 you're stuck with ActiveX)

Answer (score 1):

If you need something that works cross-browser (firefox, chrome, safari, and ie), you could look at firebreath: http://www.firebreath.org

The disadvantage to using a plugin is that users have to download and install it before it will work.

Comment: now it's as simple as installing an extension which uses an NPAPI plugin.  For instance, check out the IE Tab extension.  Although this is a browser action, not a page action as Adobe Flash would be, a similar approach could be taken to create a page-level plugin.

Comment: worth noting, however, that installing it this way will only work on the browser you install it with; i.e. mozilla extensions (even with an npapi plugin in them) don't work in chrome, and vise versa

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at this book [Programming Netscape Plug-Ins](http://docs.rinet.ru/Plugi/index.htm)